# Create Reactjs Component like Carousel using css

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, carousel, react-functional-component

I'm working on react functional component that initially contains 1 cards like the following:

[image: Initial State]

When i fill the fields and hit enter, i want to animate this to left and make it smaller and create another one like the picture:

[image: When first cards inserted]

And finally, when i have one box in left side and another in center and again i fill data and hit enter, i want to hide the small box in left with animation and animate filled box to left with resize and add new item from right side with animations that starts with 0px width and height goes larger while moving to center like following:
[image: What i want]

Always i see the box for new in center and if i have registered any record, i have one previous box with smaller size.
And the animation is important

All that i want is somthing like Carousel. I spent a lot of time but did not get results.

I need the css hero helps to get me out of hole.

Thanks to All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of hard work, finally i got it. I answerd my question for those with same requirement.

```js
import { Typography, TextField, Box } from "@mui/material"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../layout'
import styles from './serial.module.css';

const Serial = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        items: [
            {
                serial: '',
                activity: ''
            },
        ],
        newItem: {
            serialRegistered: false,
            serial: '',
            activity: ''
        }
    })

    const serialInputRef = useRef();
    const activityInputRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (serialInputRef.current, activityInputRef.current) {
            if (state.newItem.serialRegistered === false) {
                serialInputRef.current.focus();
            }
            else {

                activityInputRef.current.focus();
            }
        }

    }, [state])

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', direction: 'ltr' }}>
                {


                    state.items.map((item, index) => {
                        console.log(state.items);
                        if (index === state.items.length - 1 && state.items.length > 1) { // new

                            return (
                                <div className={styles.i1}>
                                    <Typography>
                                        {item.serial}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <br />
                                    <Typography>
                                        {item.activity}
                                    </Typography>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        else if (index === state.items.length - 2 || state.items.length === 1) { // current
                            return (
                                <div className={styles.i2}>
                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            inputRef={serialInputRef}
                                            label="سریال"
                                            placeholder='سریال'
                                            value={state.newItem.serial}
                                            margin="normal"
                                            disabled={state.newItem.serialRegistered}
                                            required fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete=""

                                            onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                                if (e.code === 'Enter') {
                                                    setState(prev => {
                                                        return {
                                                            ...prev,
                                                            newItem: {
                                                                ...prev.newItem,
                                                                serialRegistered: true,
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                } else {
                                                    setState(prev => {
                                                        return {
                                                            ...prev,
                                                            newItem: {
                                                                ...prev.newItem,
                                                                serial: prev.newItem.serial + e.key,
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            onBlur={(e) => {
                                                if (state.newItem.serialRegistered === false) {
                                                    e.target.focus()
                                                }
                                            }} />
                                    </Box>

                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            inputRef={activityInputRef}
                                            label="فعالیت"
                                            placeholder='فعالیت'
                                            margin="normal"
                                            value={state.newItem.activity}
                                            required fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete={false}
                                            onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                                if (e.code === 'Enter') {
                                                    setState(prev => {
                                                        console.log("prev", prev)
                                                        console.log("prev 1", prev.items.slice(0, prev.items.length - 1));
                                                        console.log("prev 1", prev.items.slice(0, prev.items.length - 2));

                                                        return {
                                                            ...prev,
                                                            items: [...prev.items.slice(0, prev.items.length - 1), prev.newItem, {
                                                                serial: '',
                                                                activity: ''
                                                            }],
                                                            newItem: {
                                                                serialRegistered: false,
                                                                serial: '',
                                                                activity: ''
                                                            },
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                } else {
                                                    setState(prev => {
                                                        return {
                                                            ...prev,
                                                            newItem: {
                                                                ...prev.newItem,
                                                                activity: prev.newItem.activity + e.key,
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            onBlur={(e) => {
                                                if (state.newItem.serialRegistered === true) {
                                                    e.target.focus()
                                                }
                                            }} />
                                    </Box>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        else if (index === state.items.length - 3) { // previous
                            return (
                                <div className={styles.i3}>
                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            size="small"
                                            label="سریال"
                                            placeholder='سریال'
                                            value={item.serial}
                                            margin="normal"
                                            disabled
                                            fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete="" />
                                    </Box>

                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            size="small"
                                            label="فعالیت"
                                            placeholder='فعالیت'
                                            margin="normal"
                                            value={item.activity}
                                            disabled
                                            fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete={false} />
                                    </Box>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        else if (index === state.items.length - 4) { // 2 previous
                            return (
                                <div className={styles.i4}>
                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            className={styles.i4Content}
                                            size="small"
                                            label="سریال"
                                            placeholder='سریال'
                                            value={item.serial}
                                            margin="normal"
                                            disabled
                                            required fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete="" />
                                    </Box>

                                    <Box style={{ width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }} component="form" noValidate onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            className={styles.i4Content}
                                            size="small"
                                            label="فعالیت"
                                            placeholder='فعالیت'
                                            margin="normal"
                                            value={item.activity}
                                            required fullWidth focused autoFocus
                                            autoComplete={false} />
                                    </Box>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        else {
                            return (<></>)
                        }
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Serial
```

```css
.i1 {
  /* new */
  display: none;
}

.i2 {
  /* current */
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #bdb6b6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  animation-name: i2kf;
  -webkit-animation-name: i2kf;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes i2kf {
  from {
    opacity: .6;
    transform: scale(.1);
    right: -350px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 210px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    right: 0px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 210px;
  }
}

.i3 {
  /* prev */
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 130px;
  /* transform: scale(.5); */
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #bdb6b6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  animation-name: i3kf;
  -webkit-animation-name: i3kf;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* animation-delay: .2ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s; */
}

@keyframes i3kf {
  from {
    right: -400px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 210px;
    /* transform: scale(.1); */
  }
  to {
    right: 0px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 130px;
  }
}

.i4 {
  /* prev */
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #bdb6b6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  /* display: none; */
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: i4kf;
  -webkit-animation-name: i4kf;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  /* animation-delay: .1ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .1s; */
}

@keyframes i4kf {
  from {
    transform: scale(.9);
    right: -260px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    /* transform: scale(0); */
    right: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.i4Content {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: i4kfContent;
  -webkit-animation-name: i4kfContent;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes i4kfContent {
  from {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

It's my first code snippet and i could not resolve error. I have some dependancy like material-ui and some other Component.

If you remove Layout and add dependancy, it works fine.